# There Was No 404 CMS Page Configured or Found

Tags: php, magento

I have set up multiple websites: one is basic Magento folder, and another in a separate folder inside Magento folder (which has got an index file and the .htaccess file). I get the error: `There was no 404 CMS page configured or found` when I go to the category top menu.

The main site has no changes in htaccess file:

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

The 2nd site i.e: magento/mywebsite:

```
RewriteBase /Ki-cartonn/
```

Main site index file:

```
                  $compilerConfig = 'includes/config.php';
                  $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
                  umask(0);
                  Mage::run();
```

2nd site: $compilerConfig =

```
                         '..includes/config.php';
                         $mageFilename = '..app/Mage.php';
                         umask(0);
                         Mage::run('mywebsite','website');
```

I have set the configuration properly and the categories. Works fine in local. How can I figure out this mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to put

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Before the rule on the `.htacess` on your parent folder so it excludes existing files and folders